# How to focused the InputLabel of Material UI?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

When the page loads i want to `InputLabel` to be like in the second picture, but I didn't find any`InputLabel` props to do it ,i did use the `focused` prop but it didn't work the way i wanted

And one more question according to the M-Ui docs when `shrink` prop is true the `InputLabel` should shrink but it's doing the opposite (that's the result I want but I thought `shrink={false}` would do that)

[image]

[image: [![enter image description here][2]][2] [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cAtN.png]

```
<FormControl className={styles.formControl} variant="outlined">
        <InputLabel shrink={true} focused={true}>States</InputLabel>
        <Select native
          value={value}
          onChange={inputEvent}
          label="States"
        >
          {fetchedStates.map((states, i) => (
            <option key={states + i} value={states}>
              {states}
            </option>
          ))}
        </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `autoFocus` prop to keep the focus on your `Select` component.

```
<Select
   autoFocus
   open={this.state.open}
   value={this.state.age}
   onChange={this.handleChange}
>
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-w6dyf?file=/demo.js

Reference: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9599#issuecomment-437697170